# Firefox v45 doesn't start on it own

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I recently uninstalled Mozilla Firefox v47 becuase it was not working with Selenium WebDriver. I then installed Firefox v45.0 which is working successfully with Selenium WebDriver.

The problem is that now,  cant open Firefox on it own. I double click the application icon and nothing happens. I have tried to run it as an admin, from the program files folder and still nothing happens.

I have no idea how to identify what's wrong.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This started happening when I started working with Selenium WebDriver. I want to ensure that its not because of that

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try to install version 46 of Firefox (it works with the latest version of selenium WebDriver) :
https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/46.0.1/

Comment: The 2.53.0 release notes for Selenium last mention FF45 as a supported version, as a note in version 2.52.0 and 2.50.0, and just mentioning it, not officially saying so.  I would say that using anything later than that might work, but I am not seeing an reference to using a Firefox later than that.  https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG